# ASP.NET popup The file have been changed externally

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with an ASP.NET WebForm App. From time to time I get :

[image]

I do change Web.config. When I build shouldn't abc.dll.config  auto build also?

Why does project want to reload this into solution Anyway? My unserstaning is this is not an IDE file, but a runtime config.

Comment: Do you have the file open in a tab somewhere?

Comment: I have Web.config open in a tab. But not this file.